# Query regarding jmeter thread group

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-4.0

My requirement is to run one screen with 100 users. When i want to run with 100 users which below scenario  i have to run.

Scenario 1: 100 threads, 10rampup, 1 loop count.
scenario2: 50 threads, 10rampup, 2 loop count.
scenario3: 10 threads, 10rampup, 10 loop count.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what to you mean by "screen" and "with 100 users"

1. For your "Scenario 1" JMeter will start 10 users every second
2. Once started each "user" will execute Samplers upside down
3. When there are no more [samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) to execute the user will shut down

So depending on the number of Samplers and the application response time you might not have 100 concurrent users as it might be the case that some users will already finish accessing the "screen" and some of them will not be yet started. See [JMeter Test Results: Why the Actual Users Number is Lower than Expected](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-test-results-why-actual-users-number-lower-expected) for more information.

So depending on what you're  trying to achieve you can do one of the following:

1. Set loop count to `-1` or tick "Infinite" box and specify the desired test duration. For example below setup will make 100 users hitting the "screen" for 1 minute:

   [image]
2. If you want 100 users to hit the "screen" at exactly the same moment and that's it add a [Synchronizing Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) and remove ramp-up from the Thread Group

   [image]